# predicting the future in a stationary stochastic process

Tags: autocorrelation, stochastic-processes, stationarity, spectral-analysis

Let's say I have a strictly-stationary stochastic process with known PSD (power spectral density). The process has been running, and I have all the data from time $t=-\infty$ to $t=0$.

I want to predict the value at time $t=\tau>0$. Is there a way to quantify how accurate my prediction can be, as a function of $\tau$?

[I know how to calculate the decay of the autocorrelation function. But I'm not sure that's the right answer, because I have more information than just one known data point.]

Comment: Would you like to add the constraint that the process is stationary in the wide-sense?  Such a constraint, by definition, gives you the knowledge that the expectation value of the process is independent of time, and the 2-time correlation function is only dependent upon the time difference.

Comment: @JQK - Indeed, I already said that the process is strictly stationary. (All strictly stationary processes are also wide-sense stationary.)

Comment: I missed the word "strictly"